# Which institution's logo to add to research poster when research was done at institution different to main affiliation as student?

Tags: poster

I am a student at the North Carolina School of Science and Mathematics, but did research over the summer at Duke with a mentor from Duke, as part of a program run by NCSSM. I am currently creating a poster to present my work, and I do not know which institution's logo it would be appropriate to include. When I am adding a logo to my poster, what am I acknowledging that the owner of the logo has provided? It seems to me that both institutions have provided me with support, so I do not know which one I should acknowledge. I suppose that I could add both, but I would rather save that space for content. What is the protocol for situations such as this one where two institutions have provided support to a project?

Comment: Unless the institutions have formal requirement to include their logos (which, I believe, is rather rare) you can also acknowledge support with plain text, if space is a concern.

Comment: As a side important note - Logos are important. But equally important  make sure to keep the co-authors/collaborators nformed and send all of them draft versions for comment. (They would have opinions about logos and such). It sounds from OP description that even if the poster is 'single author' there the faculty mentor at Duke shouldn't be forgotten and would be the person even if it is only for practicing professional courtesy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If both institutions have supported your project, you should acknowledge both in your poster.

To save space, you have a variety of options:

- Make the logos smaller by scaling them.
- If available, use a small, square version of the logo rather than a larger rectangular version.
- Put the logos in a part of the poster that is underutilized. (For example, left-align the title and authors, and put the logos over to the right side next to the author list.)

Comment: With the catch that if I don't have enough space to add a logo, probably I already have things to many in my poster.

Comment: “Make the logos smaller by scaling them.” — Most institutes (’s corporate design/outreach departments) hate that, and quite a few (all?) have explicit rules about the minimal size of their logos. But to be honest everybody happily ignores these rules anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There is no formal protocol. The general protocol is to ask your supervisor or colleagues. This is usually a question that depends on the particular group or institution, and where usually the "group's habits" is the precedence that you want to follow.

The general protocol that probably suit you well is the one [ff524 answered](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/73235/13552), namely, acknowledge both.

Answer (score 2):

Just one question: **Who paid?**

If they

- paid you to do the work
- paid for you to present the work
- bought the equipment or the consumables
- paid the mentor who guided you through the work

they you should be recognizing them.

And there is nothing wrong with having multiple logos, but no pressing need to have any at all. (In my business—particle physics—it is common to have everyone from the group display a logo on their slides/posters as part of establishing a brand, but those were always small because *everyone* was concerned about space.)

If someone asks you can tell them how it happened that you got support from multiple sources.